# new PowerShell code does not get executed | Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have a really wierd problem when I write a PowerShell script using Visual Studio Code. 
After I finish executing my script I make some changes to the script, but when I start the script again, these changes do not get executed. 
I thought maybe I have to little RAM, but I use a Lenovo T570 with 8GB. 

Also sometimes during debugging my script I get a error message which says: PowerShell terminated unexpectedly.

 does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?
I use VS Code 1.30 and the latest PowerShell Add-In

Comment: If the Powershell script you talk about is using a module that you have changed, these changes will not take effect if that module was already loaded into memory. You can try and force the updated module to reload by `Remove-Module xxx` before importing it with `Import-Module xxx`. You can also try using the `Force` parameter on the `Import-Module` cmdlet. If that is NOT the case here, please show us some code where the problem lies.

Comment: @theo Thank you so much! This solved my problem :)

Comment: I have posted the comment as answer now. You may consider accepting it by clicking the faint checkmark image next to it. This will help others having the same problem finding it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Powershell script is using a module that you have changed, these changes will not take effect once that module was already loaded into memory.

You can try and force the updated module to reload by adding

```
Remove-Module xxx
```

before importing it with

```
Import-Module xxx
```

You can also try using the `-Force` parameter on the Import-Module cmdlet:

```
Import-Module xxx -Force
```